# Visual studio 2010: Where is variable like $(...)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build-process

I would like to know where variables like`$(...)` are declared and how to define a custom one.

I mean, when you open a C# project configuration file (`.csproj`) there are a lot of variable like: `$(SolutionDir)`, `$(MSBuildBinPath)` - where are these configured?

If I want to create a custom one to use within a `.csproj` file to point to somewhere, how to do this?

Comment: What are you talking about? What language? What context? Visual Studio supports many different languages, so just telling us what IDE you use is no help.

Comment: This is nothing to do with standard VS languages, looks more like jQuery but this is a javascript plugin and the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: In C# `$` isn't a valid variable name. This isn't javascript.

Comment: If your three took some time and read the question, you'd see it's perfectly valid, and you just misunderstood it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - If you look at the edit history (link next to the word `edited`), you will see that is most certainly was not something understandable.

Comment: @Oded, oh, you're right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just Visual Studio internal variables. You can however use regular Windows system variable in VS using the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

These are [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) properties - they are defined in different [`.targets` files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164312.aspx) and some are passed in to the compiler on the command line.

You can declare custom properties (aside from the [well known](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) ones) and either have them in `.targets` files that you include in the `.csproj` file or pass them [on the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), where you can also override well known property defaults.

The syntax for properties is:

```
/property:name=value
```

Where `name` would be used in the `.csproj` file as `$(name)`.